# It's possible to transfer some data (value, attribute) from geonodes to cycles/eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I need to transfer some data from geonodes to cycles/eevee.
The geometry nodes are changing the size of the instances. I want to change the color of the material depending on the size.
[image]